# check items programmatically in setMultiChoiceItems in android dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-dialog

I am using a checked `ListView` in a dialog. I am able to get all the checked items ans store it like this:

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(arr, null,
        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            // indexSelected contains the index of item (of which checkbox checked)
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    brandNameIDMap.put(brandList.getItem(indexSelected).getProductID(), brandList.getItem(indexSelected).getProductName());
                    //Log.i("ID", "onClick: "+brandList.getItem(indexSelected).getProductID());
                    //seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                } else{
                    brandNameIDMap.remove(brandList.getItem(indexSelected).getProductID());
                }
            }
        });
```

**PROBLEM:**
Now I want to reopen the `Dialog` and the items that were selected previously needs to be selected automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array

```
Boolean checked[] = new Boolean[arr.size()];
```

Then onchecking any item add that to the array like this.

```
 builder.setMultiChoiceItems(arr, checked,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                // indexSelected contains the index of item (of which checkbox checked)
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                    boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        checked[indexSelected]=true;
                        brandNameIDMap.put(brandList.getItem(indexSelected).getProductID(), brandList.getItem(indexSelected).getProductName());
                        //Log.i("ID", "onClick: "+brandList.getItem(indexSelected).getProductID());
                        //seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                    } else{
                        checked[indexSelected]=false;
                        brandNameIDMap.remove(brandList.getItem(indexSelected).getProductID());
                    }
                }
            });
```